# How to running 2 queries for destroy in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Im using express to build api, and i have feature to post about data ticker and 1 post have items inside.

I tried to running 2 queries to findandremove post, and if the post exist it will be remove after that i do queries to remove the items where the items are related to the post.

```
const destroy = (req, res) => {
    DataTickerModel.findOneAndDelete({
      _id: req.params.id
    }, (err, dataTicker) => {
      if (err){
        res.send({
            success: false,
            message: 'Error: There is some error.'
        })
      } else {
        res.send({
            success: true,
            message: dataTicker.title+ ' deleted.'
        })
        DataItemModel.remove({
            dataId: {
                $in: [
                    dataTicker._id
                ]
            }
        })
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json(err)
    })
}
```

So what i expected is, if i delete a post, the items also removed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like as below:

```
const destroy = (req, res) => {
    DataTickerModel.findOneAndDelete({
      _id: req.params.id
    }, (err, dataTicker) => {
      if (err){
        res.send({
            success: false,
            message: 'Error: There is some error.'
        })
      } else {

         console.log('@@',req.params.id)
         console.log('@@',dataTicker._id)

        DataItemModel.remove({
            dataId: {
                $in: [
                    req.params.id
                ]
            }
        })

        res.send({
            success: true,
            message: dataTicker.title+ ' deleted.'
        })
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json(err)
    })
}
```

And make sure field name 'dataId' is correct

Comment: Try replacing dataTicker._id to req.params.id

Comment: ya, i tried also using params.id
but didnt work also